# Reinstall xubuntu without losing data in the home folder

Tags: xubuntu

I was using Xubuntu in my laptop. I, accidentally removed the `sources.list` file, when trying to find a solution for `apt-get` error in my system. I shut it down and the next time, I boot my system, it started to run memory tests and it went on in a loop, did not stop. Finally, I found Linux is missing from the grub menu. There were only, `memory test` and `memory testx86`.

I am not able to find a solution for this, so I planned to reinstall Xubuntu again. I have Xubuntu bootable pen drive now. But I have to do it, without losing the data from the `/home` folder. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Boot the Xubuntu Live-Usb.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

Suppose fdisk reports, /dev/sda1 = / and /dev/sda5 = /home, continue runing:

```
umount /dev/sda1
fsck -a /dev/sda1
umount /dev/sda5
fsck /dev/sda5
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
cp /etc/apt/sources.list /mnt/etc/apt/sources.list
chroot /mnt
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

In the open file paste the following lines:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Save file.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Close nano.

Continue running:

```
apt update
apt dist-upgrade
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ubuntu /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
update-grub
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/dev/pts
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt
reboot
```

Comment: It returns the following after executing 'fdisk -l', /dev/sda1 * in the boot column

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 74,5 GiB, 80032038912 bytes, 156312576 sectors
/dev/sda1  *          2048   2527231   2525184  1,2G 83 Linux   = / (root)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to reinstall the system, as it is the easiest way to go.

if you don't have the `/home` into a separate partition, you should backup your data into another drive. After that, you should be able to install Xubuntu without troubles, and you won't need to follow the next steps I'm giving you.

If the `/home` folder is in a separate partition, just start the Xubuntu installer.

When you are asked if you want to delete the disk, select the last option (I don't know how is it labeled in English, maybe More options, Something more or Advanced options) and click on Next.

Select the partition where your actual system is installed and click on Change.

Select `ext4` (or what you want) as the filesystem, `/` as the mount point and check the Format partition request. Click Accept

Select the `/home` partition (use fdisk -l or mount to know what partition is the home. It's usually the largest one in your disk) and click on Change. Select filesystem (you have to choose the actual filesystem of the partition. Again, use `fdisk -l` or `mount` to know it) and mount point (`/home`), but DON'T CHECK the Format drive option. Click on Accept and you are done.

Click on Install, confirm your changes, continue the system configuration, wait for it to be installed, etc.

When your system is fully ready-to-use, backup the `sources.list` file, so you won't need to reformat the PC if you face this issue again in the future.

Hope this helps!